# Setting visual state group from codebehind?

Tags: silverlight, controls, visualstategroup

Just wondering how I can switch between visual states in a visual state group, like if I have:

```
<SomeControl x:name="ControlName">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
       <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
          <VisualState x:Name="Me">..</VisualState>
          <VisualState x:Name="You">..</VisualState>
```

And so on and so forth, how can I from codebehind set the visual state group given?

Another question I have is, if there isa control in a control, say a Canvas, can I set individual stategroups for those seperately to the parent control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(ControlName, isMe ? "Me" : "You", true);
```

Some info here: [VisualStateManager.GoToState Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673087%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)